# geocoder.geocode() not being executed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the geocoding API to convert an address to long and lat, and then assigning a hidden input value with the recieved coordinates, instead of using this data to plot on a map.

I'm using the client facing [javascript library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple), and here is my javascript which is slightly modified.

```
<script>
        function initMap() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocodeAddress(geocoder);
            console.log('initMap');
        }

        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
            console.log('geocodeAddresses');

            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                console.log('geocoder.geocode');
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log('status OK');
                    document.getElementById('lnglat').value = results[0].geometry.location;
                    console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
                    } else {
                    console.log('status error');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

When I see the output in firebug, I can see "initmap", "geocodeAddresses" however nothing from geocoder.geocode.

I can't see any reason why, I'm not getting any errors in firebug, all of the required files are there and my API key is included and valid.

Thanks for your time

**Edit:** It appears as though geocoder.geocode isn't run at all, when I add a console.log at the end of geocodeAddress, it completely skips geocoder.geocode. Why would this be as no errors are shown in firebug.

Comment: geocoder.geocode is the event which I think gets called once conversion is done. In your case it didnt happen due to some reason. Please provide a fiddle

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v3k51h1k/) is a fiddle, I would have thought the else statement would have been executed if there was an issue, however nothing which isn't much help.

Comment: by the way are do you have maps api included in your html?
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

Comment: Yeah that's included, along with my API key too, <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey"></script>

Comment: Your code works. Check an updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/v3k51h1k/1/

Comment: The code works when the address is hardcoded, however how do I get the address from the form input and use that? I tried in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v3k51h1k/14/) however it appears the code is vulnerable to CSRF and won't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your form it will reload the page and will never call geocoder function.

Add `action="javascript:void(0);"` on `<form>` to stop it from reloading the page and `onclick` event on `<button>` to call your geocoder function.

[Check this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DatthsQhdIhqYOqQTHVj?p=preview)

```
  <body>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" id="search"> 
      <input name="query" type="text" required/>
      <input name="l" type="text" id="address" required/>
      <input name="lnglat" type="text" id="lnglat" />
      <button id="submit" onclick="query()" disabled="true">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't have `javascript:void(0);` as the form action!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Google API script comes before your javascript and you don't need a callback in the URL

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD77MKXXXX-T_xxxewvLrhFqn5cA0m-xxx"></script>`

```
function geoCode(street,city,state,zip){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = street + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myResult = results[0].geometry.location; // reference LatLng value
            var myArray = myResult.toString().slice(1, -1).split(', ');
            alert (parseFloat(myArray[0]) + parseFloat(myArray[1]));

        } else {
            alert('Map location not found.  Please adjust address.  Error: ', status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My Javascript is before, and I've removed the callback - however the geocoder.geocode still isn't being executed at all, no errors in firebug either.

Comment: Try using my geoCode function.  You are waiting on initMap() to get called but you don't need the callback at all.